# How to login users on wordpress using wp-api and oauth 1.0a in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

```
function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}
var URL = 'http://xxxxx.in/fp/design/wp-json/wp/v2/users'
var httpMethod = 'POST';
var nonce = randomString(32, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
var parameters = {
    oauth_consumer_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', //Consumer Key
    oauth_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //Token
    oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp: Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
    oauth_nonce: nonce,
    oauth_version: '1.0'
};
consumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
tokenSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
signature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, URL, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret, {
    encodeSignature: true
});
$http.post("http://xxxxxx.in/fp/design/wp-json/wp/v2/users", {
    username: 'test2',
    email: 'test2@gmail.com',
    password: 'abcd1234',
    roles: 'author'
}, {
    'headers': {
        'authorization': 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxx",oauth_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="' + Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + '",oauth_nonce="' + nonce + '",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="' + signature + '"',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }

}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I was able to create user using the api using the above code but I how do I sign with them.

I am creating an ionic app that supports login and sign up on my wordpress site.

Comment: What you did for user creation? How you are creating users?

Comment: @AkshayShah I used the above code to create users in angular using $http post method now how do I sign in with them using Oauth.